# How can I generate 2 numbers that equal a read value?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to create a bash script where I ask for a users age and then the script returns two numbers that sum to their age.

I tried

```bash
read -p "Enter your age: " age
echo $RANDOM+$RANDOM="$age"
```

When running this it printed random numbers that do not equal the age that the user inserted. I was expecting it to print two random numbers that added up to their age.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like it's been generated by a bot.

Comment: And how do you figure that two random numbers should have anything to do with your entered value?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't use 2 random numbers if their sum must be equal to the given age; one is enough:

```bash
read -p "Enter your age: " age

rand=$(( (RANDOM % (age-1)) + 1 ))  # =>  in the range [1..age-1]

echo "$rand + $(( age - rand )) = $age"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask the user for their age
echo -n "Enter your age: "
read age

# Generate two random numbers that sum up to the user's age
num1=$((RANDOM % age))
num2=$((age - num1))

# Print the two numbers
echo "The numbers are: $num1 and $num2"
```

The script above first asks for the user's age using the `echo` and then reads and saves the age using the `read`. It will then print two random numbers that when added together equals to the age that the user entered.